# Add to default field selectors with python social oauth2

Tags: django, oauth, linkedin-api, python-social-auth

I have set the SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_FIELD_OAUTH2_SELECTORS field in my Django Settings per the instructions for LinkedIn configurations here: http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/backends/linkedin.html

But when I run the authentication the additional email selector added to that setting is not added to the list of selectors in the backend call.

When I remove the field SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_FIELD_OAUTH2_SELECTORS I get an error that it is missing:

> 'Settings' object has no attribute
>   'SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_FIELD_OAUTH2_SELECTORS'

So I know I am using the correct settings name.

None of the added params make it to the backend though:

> settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_FIELD_OAUTH2_SELECTORS = ['id',
>   'recommendations-received', 'positions', 'email-address', 'headline',
>   'industry',  'first-name', 'last-name', 'location', 'num-connections',
>   'skills']

I printed out the result of the backend and always just get the default selector list:

[edited backends/linkedin.py from
https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/social/backends/linkedin.py#L32]

```
def user_details_url(self):
    # use set() since LinkedIn fails when values are duplicated
    fields_selectors = list(set(['first-name', 'id', 'last-name'] +
                            self.setting('FIELD_SELECTORS', [])))

    print fields_selectors

    # user sort to ease the tests URL mocking
    fields_selectors.sort()
    fields_selectors = ','.join(fields_selectors)
    return self.USER_DETAILS.format(fields_selectors)
```

> #> ['first-name', 'id', 'last-name']

How can I add selectors through DJANGO Settings to expand the data returned when authenticating?

Comment: I think the right parameter is to use `SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_FIELD_SELECTORS`

Comment: ALthough using that didn't cause an error non of the selctors listed for that param worked :-/ I figured a way out but it is a bit of a hack; I thknk the problem is a bug with the system. I will list it as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aamir suggestion worked!:

> **SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_FIELD_SELECTORS**

I ended up adding a print statement to social.strategies.django_strategies and got alisting of all the settings being pulled:

```
    def get_setting(self, name):
        print name
        return getattr(settings, name)
```

Listing...

```
# SOCIAL_AUTH_REDIRECT_IS_HTTPS
# REDIRECT_IS_HTTPS
# SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_KEY
# SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_SECRET 
# SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_REQUESTS_TIMEOUT 
# SOCIAL_AUTH_REQUESTS_TIMEOUT
# REQUESTS_TIMEOUT 
# SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_URLOPEN_TIMEOUT 
# SOCIAL_AUTH_URLOPEN_TIMEOUT
# URLOPEN_TIMEOUT 
# SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_FIELD_SELECTORS
```

....